# What value gets assigned to selectedItem in this line of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the line of Code:

```
var selectedItem = $("#MRadioGroup1 :checked");
```

when I put the variable in a `document.write()` statement I get an object Object on the page.
What does this mean?

Comment: Don't call `document.write()`.

Comment: Use `console.log(selectedItem);` and open your JavaScript console to see what the object is.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning an the `input` object with ID `MRadioGroup1` that is currently `checked` to that variable. To get the value of that, you could then call:

```
selectedItem.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedItem` contains a jQuery object. Any jQuery methods and properties are now available on the variable. The `object Object` is the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to get an undefined on val because you are using id - for radio buttons you should use name

```
$("input[name='MRadioGroup1']:checked").val();
```

or

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```